# Set Years to maximum in UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, github, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I am using a custom uidatepicker for my app from

https://github.com/christopherney/FlatDatePicker

The Problem is, The minimum year is 1900 (Which is Fine) but the Maximum year is 2013 (Which is not fine). How could I change this so the Maximum year is infinite or even like the year 2200 or something?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: File a bug on the project website. The `getYears` method is coded to return the current year as the maximum if no maximum has been set. That's a bad implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the maximumDate property of your date picker:

```
datePicker.maximumDate = [NSDate distantFuture];
```

Comment: Ok, But where in the code does it go, I tried it in a few places and none of them worked

Comment: You put this code after you call `[[FlatDatePicker alloc] init...];`

Comment: theoretically it should work anywhere where you have a valid reference to the datePicker. Are you sure it's not nil when you try to set the maximumDate?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[datePicker setMaximumDate:yourmaxDate];
```