# How to fix the maximum year in UIDatePicker but not date and month?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I can set the maximum date through [NSDate date] in UIPicker. But is there any way to set the maximum year only. And one more thing i want the **dates and month to roll** but **the year should be maximum to 2015 only**.

Comment: Setting a maximum date will set the maximum year.  For example if I set the maximum to Dec. 31, 2020.  The maximum with be 2020.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115449/set-years-to-maximum-in-uidatepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  //Get Current Date
    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    [DatePicker setMinimumDate:currentTime];
```

try to Set Maximum Date, it will completely set max to Year

```
    NSString *dateString = @"01-02-2010";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateFromString];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate: dateFromString];
```

Answer (score 3):

There is property of UIDatePicker

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *maximumDate
```

For more property visit the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/maximumDate)

Answer (score 1):

In attribute inspector u have an option to set the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

> I Think This Will Help You

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setYear:30];
NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
[comps setYear:-30];
NSDate *minDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];

[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```